# Multiple bakes are not working

Tags: fluid-simulation, baking

I'm stuck with a situation in my animation for fluid effect. The first time i baked the scene to check rhe results of how things will be. Then I added another object as obstacle in my domain and baked again. It shows im progress bar that its baking but the result showed rhe previous bake outcome. I removed the baked files from cache and again baked again same results. Closed the blender, restarted and baked but results were still the same as old bake. I just got too frustrated now, can anybody help pls ?

Thanks.

Comment: Not much to go on here. If you would post the blend file, it should be easy to find what is wrong. In general, the more information you give, the more likely you are to get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check the relative path and absolut path of the bake path.

check the scale of the baking domain is 1.0 in all the directions.